# what could cause Event Viewer to change the Source of the written events?? and how to solve it?

Tags: vb.net, event-viewer

I'm facing this Error for some Event Sources in my VB.NET Code:

The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( MySourceName ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details.

I searched and viewed all questions regarding this error, but I didn't find any particular reason, and I found some questions with answers that I'm already doing in my code, so what I'm asking is: how does this error occur?? and how can I solve it??